# integrating Zendesk with " Hermes " the telephony system

Tags: telephony, zendesk, zendesk-api, hermes-jms, zendesk-app

I have existing telephony system it's name " Hermes " it's a telephony system and now I want to integrate into zendesk, I have gone through Talk Partner Edition API but I am not getting exact idea.

I wanna know how should I connect this telephony system with zendesk and how should I embed this soft-phone into "Zendesk ???? Or the steps to do this work done ???

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far and why hasn't it worked?  Have you read Zendesk's own resources on how to do this?  https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/sections/360000328707

Comment: @JimmyLong thank you sir for the answer , But I didn't get the exact idea to integrate existing system with Zendesk support, there they have concentrated on developer guide in the apps framework documentation.
i want to know the steps to do this work done ??? i didn't find any tutorial :\

Comment: What are your exact goals for the integration?  You've stated you want to integrate, but not what you want to do specifically.  The resources in the link should cover every aspect of how a telephony system can integrate with Zendesk.

Comment: @JimmyLong thank you sir for the answer again ... my goal for the integration is that when the costumer call in “ Hermes ” the telephony system, i will answer he, so at the moment of the end of the call, a ticket should create in Zendesk automatically contain information about the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zendesk provides API endpoints to [search for users](https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001814168) based on phone number, as well as the ability to [create new user](https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001840787) profiles.  With the user's profile information, a new ticket can be created on behalf of the user with the [Create Ticket API endpoint](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/voice-api/talk_partner_edition#create-ticket).  A more detailed step-by-step guide can be found [here](https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001889888).

Comment: thank you sir for the answer again ... so for the code (I mean the Script who will contain the API) I should write it inside “ Hermes ” the telephony system, Or inside Zendesk or what!!
Because it seems like I will write the code in the telephony system to post data inside zindesk!!!  

Because in the documentation of Zendesk I didn't find an example to start from it, I find just the scripts of Api. even in github I didn't find something useful to start the coding. like an little demo to understand the whole principle

Comment: What language is Hermes written in?  Zendesk provides examples in a variety of common languages.

Comment: The language used to develop inside " Hermes " is the Javascript. :\

Comment: There's a couple Node.js libraries available with examples which can be found here - https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/api-clients/nodejs

Other than those, ZD examples are usually given using cURL, which you'd need to modify to fit your particular needs in Javascript.  https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/search#using-curl

Comment: in that case could you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Yes sir of course, I just want to understand something before asks you again, i post my question in this link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091689/integrating-zendesk-talk-api-code-in-the-telephony-system